# Hide an element through CSS code

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I do not know css and it seems hard to display a menu through my self-hosted wordpress site theme in the mobile version. The idea is to use the following code:

```
#sidebar-primary { display: none; }
```

Though seems that nothing happens when I add it. Is there a way to hide this element? Below is th whole code when the mobile version is present. Thanks

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .wrap { max-width: 300px; }
    #branding {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    #sidebar-header {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .featured-wrapper, .aside, .content-wrap, #content, #sidebar-subsidiary .widget, #respond { width: 100%; }
    .featured-post h2.entry-title a { 
        font-size: 12px; 
        line-height: 1.4em; 
        padding-right: 15px;
        bottom: 87px;
    }
    .featured-post .byline { 
        bottom: 63px;
        padding: .25em 15px .25em 1.3em;
    }
    .home.singular .byline { font-size: 10px; }
    .menu-toggle { 
        display: block; 
        width: 100%;
    }
    #menu-primary {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #menu-primary .menu, .menu ul { 
        float: left;
        width: 100%; 
    }
    #menu-primary ul li {
        clear: left;
        display: block;
        padding-left: 0;
        background: none;
    }
    #menu-primary ul li a {
        font-size: 20px; 
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 12px 15px;
    }
    #menu-primary li li a { font-size: 18px; }
    #menu-primary li ul, #menu-primary li li { border: none !important; }
    #menu-primary li li a:hover { background: none; }
    #menu-primary ul li ul {    
        display: block !important;
        float: left !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }
    #menu-primary li ul {
        display: block !important;
        position: relative !important;
        top: 0;
        left: 30px;
    }   
    #menu-primary ul li li ul { left: 30px !important; }
    #menu-primary li:hover ul, #menu-primary li.sfHover ul {
        display: block !important;
        top: 0 !important;
    }
    #menu-primary li:first-child ul { left: 0; }    
    #menu-primary .sf-sub-indicator { background: none !important; }


    #menu-secondary .sf-sub-indicator { background: none !important; }
    .hentry {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .page-template-front .hentry:hover .read-more, .archive .hentry:hover .read-more, .search .hentry:hover .read-more { display: none; }
    .page-template-front .hfeed-more .hentry {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .comment-list li li { padding-left: 0; }
    #sidebar-primary, #sidebar-secondary, #sidebar-subsidiary {
        width: 100%;
        clear: left;
    }
    #footer-content, #menu-subsidiary {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #menu-subsidiary .menu { float: left; }
    #menu-subsidiary li {
        background: none;
        float: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: .4em;
    }
    #menu-subsidiary li a {
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 2.5em; 
    }

    textarea { width: 96%; }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see where you're using display none for sidebar primary item in your css.

Comment: i provided the original code, it is not used in there, though when i used it is still displayed.

Comment: That means some script is not allowing your css. You may do again it in jQuery???

Comment: jquery $('#id').hide();

Comment: #sidebar-primary { display: none!important; } try this.

Comment: unfortunately still appears

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `!important` to your style?

```
#sidebar-primary { display: none; !important}
```

Comment: yes i added it just before: textarea { width: 96%; } and still appears when I inspect the element

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have not missed any other

```
@media only screen and (max-width: xyz px)
```

May be

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
```

style are not calling.

Check with other `@media` tag if exists in css.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to force the element to not be displayed is to use the css below:

```
#sidebar-primary { display: none !important;}
```

semi-colon after !important

Even if you set the display to none it will still appear when you inspect the dom element. To remove it entirely you need to use jquery or javascript the triggers on document ready that removes the element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if($(window).width() < 767){

$('#sidebar-primary').remove();


}

})
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working then it looks like the style for mobile devices are defined in different @media query

Mostly `max-width : 320px` @media query is used for mobile devices

For mobile devices `max-width : 320px` just check if it is there and add styles in that query

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

and more information on @media queries can be found [**here**](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/css3-quick-tips/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries) and [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)